# is Updating reducer initial state with localStorage data a good practice?

Tags: javascript, redux

I have a reducer with an initial state and is working fine.

```
const initialState = [items:{
    id: 1,
    text: 'Monday',
},
{   id: 1,
    text: 'Tuesday',
}];

function dayChaged(state = initialState, change) {

..
}
```

My app is working fine. However, i added a support for local storage. I want to store the new item in the storage whenever user add one. And when the page is refresh/reload, i want to set iniTialState to be the value of the iniTialState plus the localstorage values. At the moment i added this in the state/reducer class , however, i feel like this is not the best practice.

```
const storageItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items'));
if(storageItems) {
    initialState = { todos: initialState.items.concat(storageItems) };
} 
 function dayChaged(state = initialState, change) {

    ..
    }
```

Its working fine and doing what i want. However, this complicate the reducer to my understanding. Please where should i add such feature anc considering my intention, how do i fully integrate this without affecting the testability of the state?

Comment: The rule is `single source of truth`. If you are updating the data via API then you do not have to use a local storage for the state. If your app resides only on browser and does not depend on any other external APIs then local storage is a good option to keep the data persisted even after page reload

Comment: @anoop I see at least one valid use case when using local storage in combination with server-side storage - speeding up your app initialization, optimistic updates, offline apps.
To OP - consider if you really need to change initialState of your reducer OR perhaps what you need is actually setting state of your entire store (in which case initial state of your individual reducers will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

First off consider if you really need to change initialState of your reducer OR perhaps what you need is actually setting initial state of your entire store (in which case initial state of your individual reducers will be ignored).

See signature of the createStore function, it accepts initial store state as second (optional) argument, pass your state from localStorage there and you should be golden.

https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/api/createStore.md